# Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-armel/Packages'

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi..
I AM trying to install Ubuntu Arm install of ROS INDIGO ,on snapdragon QS 600. OS is linoro version 14.10.

While doing apt-get install it is giving me error as

```
Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ROS/ubuntu/dists/trust/Release Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-armel/Packaged' In release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267721/unable-to-find-expected-entry-%27main/binary-armel/packages%27/) by [Roslearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/31389/roslearner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are no binaries being built for Indigo on Ubuntu 14.10, not even for x86/amd64.

The only Ubuntu OS for which Indigo binaries are provided is Ubuntu Trusty (14.04).

See [REP-3 - Target Platforms - Indigo Igloo](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#indigo-igloo-may-2014) and [wiki/Installation/UbuntuARM](http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/UbuntuARM).

---

you could perhaps try to override OS detection ([ROS_OS_OVERRIDE](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_OS_OVERRIDE)) and add the Trusty ROS repository to your Utopic system, but I don't think I have to explain why that is not recommended.

---

Edit: also just noticed this:

```
Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ROS/ubuntu/dists/trust/Release [..]
```

`trust` is not a valid Ubuntu OS codename. Should that be `trusty` (but see earlier note)?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0